# how find the shortest distance between two numbers in a random list without sorting the list. my code is given below , i need another FAST way

Tags: python, data-structures

```
    
import random



L = [random.randrange(1, 100**7) for i in range(100*100)]
       
#it creates a random list

for x in L:
    min = L[0]
    for y in L:
        if x != y and abs(x-y) < min:
            min = abs(x-y)
**#it basically cheeks every element with every one and update the min value id new one is found**


print(min)
```

any faster way doing so without sorting?
someone suggested it can be done using a hashing table but I cant relate to it so pls help me with the logic and connection of this question with hashing table

Comment: Do you mean you cannot use sorting at all? Or you just cannot modify the input list?

Comment: I cant sort the list . they say its posible without sorting it at all

Comment: i dont knw numpy still, Im a new guy in 1st year college, new to coding so, is it possible or its kinda really hard to solve it uisng hash table, did you find the relation?

Comment: Generally, this is called the closest-pair problem and its best worst case performance is `O(N*logN)` which indciates that sorting of some kind will be involved.

Comment: ok ill check it

Comment: And try to avoid using builtin `min` as your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers can be stored in nested lists according with its binary (or whatever) representation. We use a fix digits number (for this example 3). For example 2 will be represented as `010`

Then we  put an element in

```
numbers[0][1][0]
```

The tree with just the number 2 would be:

```
[
    [None, [True, None]], None
]
```

If we add number 3 (011):

```
[
    [None, [True, True]], None
]
```

add number 1 (001):

```
[
    [[None, True], [True, True]], None
]
```

All the lists has 2 elements and are created as needed. Unused elelements are set to 'None'

We actually dont need to put the number because all the information is in the indices. So we put just `True` to say that the number 2 is in the tree.

Now to find the closer number in the tree to some other number just do a binary search.

Now compare the minimal distance with the stored minimal distance , update the stored minimal distance if needed and store the new number in the tree.

I think this O(N * logN). The log comes from the binary storage and search.